# How can I add test description to results/test report in matlab unit test framework?

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab unittesting framework and I would like to know what is the best way to add the test description in the test results with this framework.

Let's say that I have the following class

```matlab
classdef myClass < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    properties
        A;
        B;
    end
    methods (TestClassSetup)
        function assignVars(testCase)
            testCase.A = 1;
            testCase.B = 2;
        end
    end
    methods (TestClassTeardown)
    end
    methods (TestMethodSetup)
    end
    methods (TestMethodTeardown)
    end
    %% Function that perform the tests
    methods(Test,TestTags = {'A'})
       function y = addAandB(testCase)
        % This test check that A plus B is 3
            y = testCase.A + testCase.B;
       end
    end
end
```

and I am running it with the following script

```matlab
%% House keeping
clear all;
close all;
%% Imports
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner;
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.TestReportPlugin;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.XMLPlugin;
import matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin
import matlab.unittest.plugins.ToFile


%% Run unit test for sanity check and performance
loggingLevel    = 4;
% Define tests to run
suiteToRun = testsuite('myClass','Tag','A');
% Create runner for test cases and attach plugins
runner          = matlab.unittest.TestRunner.withNoPlugins;
% Enable plugin to create test report
mkdir('./testsResults');
testReportName  = 'unitTestReport';
runner.addPlugin(DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin('IncludingPassingDiagnostics',true,'OutputDetail',loggingLevel,'LoggingLevel',loggingLevel))
runner.addPlugin( matlab.unittest.plugins.TestReportPlugin.producingHTML(['./testsResults/' testReportName '.html'],'IncludingPassingDiagnostics',true,'LoggingLevel',loggingLevel))
runner.addPlugin(matlab.unittest.plugins.XMLPlugin.producingJUnitFormat(['./testsResults/' testReportName '.xml'],'OutputDetail',loggingLevel));
runner.addPlugin(matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin.producingOriginalFormat(ToFile(['./testsResults/' testReportName '.tap']),'OutputDetail',loggingLevel));
testResults = runner.run(suiteToRun);
% Show results
table(testResults)
if(exist(['./testsResults/' testReportName '.html'],'file'))
    uiopen(['./testsResults/' testReportName '.html/index.html'],1);
end
% Ensure no error happened during run
assertSuccess(testResults)
```

Which will produce the following output in matlab command

```
> In test (line 21) 
Generating test report. Please wait.
    Preparing content for the test report.
    Adding content to the test report.
    Writing test report to file.
Test report has been saved to:
 C:\LocalData\myTest\testsResults\unitTestReport.html\index.html

ans =

  1×6 table

            Name            Passed    Failed    Incomplete    Duration       Details   
    ____________________    ______    ______    __________    _________    ____________

    {'myClass/addAandB'}    true      false       false       0.0002881    {1×1 struct}


ans = 

  TestResult with properties:

          Name: 'myClass/addAandB'
        Passed: 1
        Failed: 0
    Incomplete: 0
      Duration: 2.8810e-04
       Details: [1×1 struct]

Totals:
   1 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Incomplete.
   0.0002881 seconds testing time.
```

How can I add the test description as part of the results table? So I would like to have something like below.

```
ans =

  1×6 table

            Name            Passed    Failed    Incomplete    Duration       Details     Description
    ____________________    ______    ______    __________    _________    ____________

    {'myClass/addAandB'}    true      false       false       0.0002881    {1×1 struct}   This test check that A plus B is 3
```

Also is it possible to add this description to the test report as well?
[image]

Comment: I don't know of any better way than having a lookup table of test name (e.g. `myClass/addAandB`) to description, and post-processing your test result to add that in. If you really need to get the descriptions out of the tests automatically then you can run `help` for each test name which will return the comment text that follows each `function` statement, but only to the console, so the only way I know to capture it is via the `diary` command (or parse the .m files yourself). If you really need to do it it can be done (I have built an automated documentation tool this way) but it's not fun.

Comment: THanks for the answer @nekomatic the point is that I need the description in the results :S. I am wondering why this test framework doesn't support this feature when the one of Simulink does ...

Comment: OK, I looked at the help some more and I think the nearest MATLAB gets to allowing what you want is described in [Write Plugin to Add Data to Test Results](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-plugin-to-add-data-to-test-results.html) - I can't tell you how much of your requirement that will meet, but good luck.

Comment: Thanks again @nekomatic, I have had a look into that too, but it doesn't cover what I needed, I am looking into [write-custom-plugin-to-save-diagnostic-details](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-custom-plugin-to-save-diagnostic-details.html) though